# Same results looks wrong in HackerRank

Tags: php

I am trying to learn PHP by answering questions in hackerrank.com but I am stuck on this one.

```
<?php

function plus_minus($array) {
    $dimension=count($array);
    $negative =0;
    $positive = 0;
    $zeroes = 0;
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $element>0 ? $positive++ : null;
        $element<0 ? $negative++ : null;
        $element==0 ? $zeroes++ : null;
    }
    echo number_format($positive/$dimension, 6);
    echo '<br>';
    echo number_format($negative/$dimension,6);
    echo '<br>';
    echo number_format($zeroes/$dimension, 6);
}


$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);
$arr = array_map('intval', $arr);

plus_minus($arr);

?>
```

Here a screenshot: 
[[image: 1]]

Is the question wrong or I did I make mistakes?

Comment: Did you see the editorial

Comment: what is editorial ?

Answer (score 5):

`echo '\n';`

I fixed my problem by doing this

```
print_r(number_format($positive/$dimension, 6)); 
print_r("\n");
print_r(number_format($negative/$dimension,6));
print_r("\n");
print_r(number_format($zeroes/$dimension, 6));
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 for taking the time to use something like hackerrank/topcoder/etc... to grow your skills.

Try replacing the `echo '<br>';`  with `echo '\n';`

I'm guessing the issue is HackerRank generally wants the results as they'd be displayed printing to STDOUT to a terminal or something, not rendered as HTML to be parsed and displayed by a browser.

Thus, the `echo '<br>';` are probably resulting in something that looks like this to their test case runner:

```
somevalue1<br>somevalue2<br>somevalue3...
```

but it when shown by their website your browser rendering the HTMl looks like:

```
somevalue1
somevalue2
somevalue3
...
```

due to the `<br>` being evaluated in the HTML as a newline.  Thus even thought the result looks the same, it's not, it's just the browser rendering screwing with you!

Now about your logic in general, I'm not sure ternary statements are the the best approach, but what you've got should work fine.